# Javascript Countdown With Pause & Resume

Tags: javascript

I have javascript countdown

```
var timersCount = 0;
var timerCounter = setInterval(countTimers, 30000);
countTimers();

function countTimers()
{
    timersCount++;

    var count = 26;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    function timer()
    {

        count = count-1;
        if(count < 0) {
         clearInterval(counter);
         return;
        }

        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count;
    }

document.getElementById("countTimers").innerHTML=timersCount;
}
```

HTML

```
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resue">Resume</button>
```

That function is running OK. But now I want to add Pause and Resume the countdown. Is it possible to set it to my function. Please help.

Comment: are you asking about adding button actions or stopping the interval?

Comment: Hi Oskar, I'm asking to Pause and Resume countdown timer using button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go. First, you need only one interval, second you should have some flag telling you when timer is paused. Then it is just simple logic and 2 listeners.

```js
var timersCount = 0;
var pause = false; //is timer paused

countTimers();

function countTimers() {
  timersCount++;

  var count = 26;
  var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

  function timer() {
    if (!pause) { //do something if not paused
      count = count - 1;
      if (count < 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        setTimeout(countTimers, 5000); //start count from 26 again
        return;
      } 

      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("countTimers").innerHTML = timersCount;
}

document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function () {
 pause = true;
});

document.getElementById('resume').addEventListener('click', function () {
 pause = false;
});
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
<span id="countTimers"></span>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resume">Resume</button>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I have tried your code and it works. But when I click pause, time countTimers is still running. How can I pause it too? And I want to make rest about 5 seconds then start it again countdown var timerCounter = setInterval(countTimers, 30000);

Comment: @DavidAlwis it is not running, as in my code you never start it. There is no need for it. You should never use interval for countTimers function. If you want rest period, just change ``countTimers()`` to ``setTimeout(countTimers, 5)`` in my code, where ``if (count < 0) {`` is.

Comment: Hi @sielakos, assuming if I want to make rest about 5 seconds wait after that start it again. Is it possible?

Comment: @DavidAlwis Yeah, I just give you answer in comment, just use ``setTimeout(countTimers, 5000)``, before I made mistake, it should be in milliseconds not seconds.

Comment: @DavidAlwis I changed my answer, to show you full example with 5 seconds resting period.

Comment: Hi @sielakos just tried your code and it works. But when I pause it in rest 5 seconds, the countTimers is still running.

Comment: @DavidAlwis It is not, because there is no countTimers interval started, at least not in my code. You seem to have hard time understanding this, there no such interval started, because there is no need for it. You were mistaken in first place to ever start it.