# I can't figure how to stop the function in the middle

Tags: javascript

I have a 1min countdown and I cant figure how to do the following task:
If I will press the button , I want it to stop and then continue from the same point it had stopped.
Also I'm feeling that I wrote too much code for very simple task.
Does anyone got better suggestion?

I tried to put continue and break but I couldn't figure how to put them since it doesnt combined with if/else conditioning.

The timer is displaying like this : 00:00
and counts down , with "start" button below this.

```
const startButton = document.querySelector("button");
startButton.onclick = function countdown() {
let sixtySeconds = 60;
let sixtyMinutes = 0;
document.querySelectorAll("span")[0].innerHTML = "0" +sixtyMinutes;
let timer = setInterval( function theTimer(){
  sixtySeconds--;
  if (sixtySeconds >= 10){
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[1].innerHTML = sixtySeconds;
  } else if (sixtySeconds < 10){
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[1].innerHTML = "0" + sixtySeconds;
  } else {
     document.querySelectorAll("span")[1].innerHTML = "00";
  }
  if (sixtySeconds === 0 || sixtyminutes < 60){
    sixtyMinutes++;
    document.querySelectorAll("span")[0].innerHTML = "0" +sixtyMinutes;
   clearInterval(timer);
  } 
}, 1000);
 return countdown();
}
```

Comment: are you allowed to use jquery?

Comment: Basically you want to make a countdown timer with pause and resume functionality. Is that it?

Comment: @TanmayGawankar Excactly. I have only one button there.

Comment: @SASSY_ROG No I don't

Comment: checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38539312/9172668) answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can archive this by using objects

```js
var myTimer = {

timeOut: 60,
currentTime: 0,
myTime: undefined,
startTimer: function() {
    myTimer.myTime = setInterval(function() {
        if(myTimer.currentTime>myTimer.timeOut) myTimer.pauseTime()
        console.log(myTimer.currentTime++)
        // Do your printing Here of currentTime
    },1000)
},
pauseTime: function() {
    clearInterval(myTimer.myTime)
}

}
```

```html
<button onclick="myTimer.startTimer()">start</button>

<button onclick="myTimer.pauseTime()">pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive that by calling `setInterval` and `clearInterval` along with a flag for pausing when the button is clicked, please check below code:

```js
let timerRef;
let targetCount = 60;
let currentCount = 60;
let stopTimer = false;
let controlButton = document.getElementById('controlButton');
let countLabel = document.getElementById('count');

startTimer();


function startTimer(){
  timerRef = setInterval(function() {
    if(currentCount == 0 || stopTimer){
      clearInterval(timerRef);
    }
    else {
      currentCount--; 
      countLabel.innerText = currentCount;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function pause() {
  if(stopTimer == true){
  stopTimer = false;
  controlButton.innerText = 'Pause';
  startTimer();
  }
  else {
  stopTimer = true;
  controlButton.innerText = 'Continue';
  }
};
```

```html
<div id='count'>60</div>
<button id='controlButton' onclick='pause()'>Pause</button>
```

Comment: OP wants to make a timer

Comment: and with ability to interrupt it onClick

Comment: please check my updated answer @Yong Quan  and Tanmay Gawankar thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Have a Look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xfz8pc2w/

I haven't applied the formatting of timing yet. Let me know if this is your requirement.

Single button starts, pauses and resumes the timer.

I have applied the flag logic

```
var action=function(){
    if( NextFlag=="Start" || NextFlag=="Resume"){
    myVar = setInterval(CountdownFunc,1000);
    NextFlag="Pause";
  }else if( NextFlag=="Pause"){
    clearInterval(myVar);
    NextFlag="Resume";
  }
};
```